# Need assistance storing MYClass object in core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to save my class instance to coredata

```
MYClass *myClassObject = [[MYClass alloc]init];
```

I defined attribute type to transformable

created new subclass of NSValueTransformable

implemented its four methods

```
+ (BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation
{
    return YES;
}

+ (Class)transformedValueClass
{
    return [NSData class];
}

- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
}
```

set the subclass in attribute inspector

I dont know what to implement in these methods

```
- (id)transformedValue:(id)value
{
    // ?
}

- (id)reverseTransformedValue:(id)value
{
    // ?
}
```

So I can save and fetch objects.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Writing a Custom Value Transformer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ValueTransformers/Concepts/CustomTransformer.html) in the "Value Transformer Programming Guide"? That guide contains concrete examples.

Answer (score -1):

According to me the most easiest way to do this is will be via NSCoding.You can refer the below link for NSCoding implementation, the tutorial is basically is to save the class instances to plist but in your case you can save the same in core data. http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/how-to-save-your-app-data-with-nscoding-and-nsfilemanager